# Convert a string with $N^2$ entries to a rank-$N$ matrix

Tags: matrix, export, import, string-manipulation

Suppose we are given a set of numeral data like a string that consists of $N^2$ entries, say $N$ is very large (here $N=8$ for simplicity, but $N$ can be $10^8$...)

```
2 −1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

−1 2 −1 0 0 0 0 0

0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0 0

0 0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0

0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0 −1 

0 0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0

0 0 0 0 0 − 1 2 0 

0 0 0 0 −1 0 0 2
```

How do we use Mathematica to input this string and output its matrix form as a rank-$N$, namely $N$ by $N$, matrix in an efficient way? Say in both the MathML input font and the LaTex font?

I expect the output will be in,

LaTex font:

```
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
```

MathML input font:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix},$$

or the one written in Table with two layers of brackets,
the first layer brackets has 8 brackets inside,
the second layer brackets has 8 number inside.

{{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}}

Question -- Can we obtain this final Table form with two layers of brackets?

Answer (score 5):

You keep referring to "font", so maybe your question is about displaying the data, but if it's just about getting the string data into a numeric list format, then you can just use `ImportString`.

I copy-pasted your string just as you provided it, so I also included a cleaning step:

```
data = "2 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

\[Minus]1 2 \[Minus]1 0 0 0 0 0

0 \[Minus]1 2 \[Minus]1 0 0 0 0

0 0 \[Minus]1 2 \[Minus]1 0 0 0

0 0 0 \[Minus]1 2 \[Minus]1 0 \[Minus]1 

0 0 0 0 \[Minus]1 2 \[Minus]1 0

0 0 0 0 0 \[Minus] 1 2 0 

0 0 0 0 \[Minus]1 0 0 2";
ImportString[StringReplace[data, {"\n\n" -> "\n", "\[Minus] " -> "-", "\[Minus]" -> "-"}], "Table"]

(*
  {{2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, -1}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 2}}
*)
```

Comment: Could you explain this: ImportString[StringReplace[data, {"\n\n" -> "\n", "\[Minus] " -> "-", "\[Minus]" -> "-"}], "Table"] for me in detail? How does each function work?

Comment: `ImportString[..., "Table"]` is saying to import it as a table, a list of data, and it'll automatically try to interpret the data as mathematica expressions (so numbers in this case). The `StringReplace[...]` is there to clean up the data: `"\n\n" -> "\n"` gets rid of the extra blank lines, `"\[Minus] " -> "-"` handles that one weird case with the extra space on the second-to-last line of data, and `"\[Minus]" -> "-"` handles all the rest of the "\[Minus]" cases ("\[Minus]" would be interpreted as a string character, not the numeric negative sign).

Comment: Thanks this works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

The way I did this is pretty messy, so maybe someone can improve on this:

First I replace `"\[Minus] "` with `"\[Minus]"` in the 7th row because theres an extra space there. I then replace `"\[Minus]"` with `-`. There is a distinction between `\[Minus` and `-` : it appears `Interpreter` only works with `-` here

```
str = "2 −1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

−1 2 −1 0 0 0 0 0

0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0 0

0 0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0

0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0 −1 

0 0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0

0 0 0 0 0 − 1 2 0 

0 0 0 0 −1 0 0 2";

str = StringReplace[str, "\[Minus] " -> "\[Minus]"];
str = StringReplace[str, "\[Minus]" -> "-"];
```

I then use `DelimitedSequence` to interpret `str` as a sequence of integers:

```
interp = 
  Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Integer"]][str];
n = Sqrt@Length@interp;
mat = ArrayReshape[interp, {n, n}];
mat//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For LaTeX input, I `Riffle` an ampersand and a LaTeX new line \ at the end of each row. Then convert back `ToString` and `StringJoin` all together:

```
addDings = Riffle[#, " & "] & /@ mat;
out = Append[#, " \\\\ \n"] & /@ addDings;
latex = StringJoin[ToString /@ Flatten@out];
(*drop last \\ and add \begin and \end*)
latex = StringDrop[latex, -4];
StringJoin["\\begin{pmatrix}\n", latex, " \n\\end{pmatrix}"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a sanity check I test the output by pasting it here (I copied the output from the above code block as Plain Text and put it here enclosed with a pair of `$$`):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the new latex interface to interpret your text? Basically, you enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-4, then enter the tex into the cell, and then hit enter. Here is a short video where I do this:

[image]

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question, but I thought @zeta was asking how to get latex commands as output, given string input. So I don't think they have the latex commands to input into the latex interface. I could have just misinterpreted the question though.

Comment: Thanks, but the starting point is this string: 2 −1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

−1 2 −1 0 0 0 0 0

0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0 0

0 0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0

0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0 −1 

0 0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0

0 0 0 0 0 −1 2 0 

0 0 0 0 −1 0 0 2

Comment: @CarlWoll I haven’t been able to find documentation of this useful feature. Does the rendered  LaTeX become a usable object or is it formatted text…obviously I’ll test when I get a chance. Thanks for highlighting this feature. +1 of course

Comment: This is still very nice, please keep it - I voted up.